# an indentity for wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

If $u(x, t)$ satisfies the wave equation $u_{t t}=u_{x x}$ , then
\begin{align}
u(x+h, t+k)+u(x-h, t-k)=u(x+k, t+h)+u(x-k, t-h)\end{align}
for all $x, t, h,$ and $k .$

This is an exercise (exercise 4,pp41) in the Strauss's monograph Partial Differential Equations.

What is the meaning of this identity?

Comment: it's called the parallelogram law.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is a very useful hint! @qbert